# DataTable returning only one row when there must be multiple rows on VB.Net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datatable

**DataTable** returning **only one row** when there must be **multiple rows** as I load:

```
Dim comm As New MySqlCommand
Dim conn As New MySqlConnection
With comm
.CommandText = "SELECT tblSupplierPO.supplier_POID, tblSupplier.supplier_name, tblSupplierPO.supplier_PODate, tblCategory.category_description, tblSupplierPOList.part_num, tblSupplierPOList.item_name, tblSupplierPOList.order_qty, tblUnit.unit_name FROM tblSupplierPO INNER JOIN tblSupplierPOList ON tblSupplierPO.supplier_POID = tblSupplierPOList.supplier_POID INNER JOIN tblSupplier ON tblSupplierPO.supplier_id = tblSupplier.supplier_id INNER JOIN tblUnit ON tblSupplierPOList.unit_id = tblUnit.unit_id INNER JOIN tblCategory ON tblSupplierPOList.category_id = tblCategory.category_id WHERE tblSupplierPOList.supplier_POID LIKE  'po-1010'"
.connection = conn
.ExecuteNonQuery
End With
```

Then load this to my DataTable...

```
DataTable1.Load(comm.ExecuteReader)
```

And when I tested it using messagebox...

```
MsgBox(DataTable1.Rows.Count)
```

It Only Returns one row... But when i copy pasted the commandText to PhpMyAdmin SQL and Run it, it shows the complete 5 rows. A little help here please... Thanks!

I Use MS VisualStudio2012

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `ExecuteReader` gives you a forward-only cursor, which deals with one row at a time. To fill a data table, try a data adapter. The first code example on [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqldataadapter.html) shows how.

Comment: One other thing: I scrolled a few feet to the right and saw your query ends with `WHERE tblSupplierPOList.supplier_POID LIKE 'po-1010'`. If your real code substitutes a user-supplied value here you're open to SQL Injection, which is not good. I'd recommend prepared statements, which work well with data adapters. There's an example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare.aspx).

Comment: Also, you should know that this line `.ExecuteNonQuery` runs the query and gives you the number of records, and then later you run it again, so you ran the query twice against your database for no reason. Take that line out, it is not needed.

Comment: but i need to use a `DataTable` because I need those data to be displayed on **Crystal Report** and I don't think using a `DataAdapter` will display my data on my CReport correclty...

Comment: Just as a note, the `comm.ExecuteReader` will successfully fill a `DataTable` without issue. `DataAdapter` is not required for this.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [MySqlDataAdapter](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqldataadapter.html) to `Fill` your `DataTable`.

Comment: Thanks Thanks Thanks! :) It really works! Very Simple answer Sir!